# Android - capturing hardware button presses while in locked mode

Tags: android

We would like to be able to capture hardware button presses (long clicks) in android 2.3 when the device is locked.

There is a problem to listen to "Volume_changed" event, as it does not change while the phone is locked.

How can I find the intents fired after pressing the hardware volume button?
I know that it is problematic for services to listen to these events, but is it possible to start an activity as a result of this press, when we are in locked mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> We would like to be able to capture hardware button presses (long clicks) in android 2.3 when the device is locked.

This is not possible.

> There is a problem to listen to "Volume_changed" event, as it does not change while the phone is locked.

In your activity, you can call `setVolumeControlStream()` to determine what the volume buttons control while the phone is locked and your activity is in the foreground. For a service, near as I can tell, the volume buttons are handled by the audio focus system.

> How can I find the intents fired after pressing the hardware volume button?

There are no such `Intents`.

> but is it possible to start an activity as a result of this press, when we are in locked mode?

No, sorry.

Comment: Thanks!

Could you perhaps suggest a way for us to listen to the pattern lock buttons being pressed? Or any way to "wake" an application and place an activity in front of the lock screen when a hardware button is pressed?